# What is the font used in the inco mobile logo the blue one

Tags: font-identification

[image]

What is the font used in the inco mobile logo the blue one

Answer (score 1):

That 'S' is fairly unique. Looks like architect's blueprint labeling handwriting. Searching for 'architect type' I found what appears to be a match:

[Architects Daughter by Kimberly Geswein](http://www.kimberlygeswein.com/2010/12/06/new-architects-daughter/)

[image]

Freeware for personal use. Donationware for commercial use.